# "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda

Here is what I am trying to accomplish: I have a Particle and I am trying to transfer data from that to my MySQL database stored on AWS.

For reference, this is the guide I am following: https://medium.com/@mohkil87/how-to-store-data-generated-by-particle-devices-to-aws-rds-mysql-using-webhooks-343bc780c824

I have everything set up properly, but I cannot for the life of me get past this issue with the Lambda code. the error I am getting:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
"errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported"
```

this is what my code looks like for index .js:
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbvu9.jpg)

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    user : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
    password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    port : process.env.RDS_PORT,
    database : process.env.RDS_DATABASE
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const sql = "INSERT INTO `ParticleDeviceData` (event, data, coreid, published_at) VALUES ('" + event['event']+"','" + event['data']+"','" + event['coreid']+"','" + event['published_at'] + "')";
    
    con.query(sql, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        callback(null, '1 records inserted.');
    });
};
```

for package .json:
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1LSU.jpg):

```
{
  "name": "logdatatodb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

keep in mind, this guide I am using is who knows how old, and I also have very little experience with any of this. From what I can tell, it seems like a node_module or dependency error. I assume its as simple as getting the module folder and adding it to dependency or something, but I have no real clue how or where to add that in.

edit: I am now seeing this message: "Lambda can't find the file index.js. Make sure that your handler upholds the format: file-name.method."

how can it not find index.js? it is in the root directory???

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! You should post the code snippets as text in your question instead of as images. This helps others (and search engines) to find relevant questions but it also helps people answering you.

Comment: gotcha, ill do that now. i did it as an image because the ide has a layout of files where my solution is different than what people would initially suggest (move index.js up one file but i cant)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the AWS Lambda console. You need to move the index.js to the root directory (i.e., one level up the current path) because index.handler is looking for a function named handler at index.js in your root directory.

Comment: yes, AWS Lamda. index.js is currently in the root directory. It does not go any higher than that. i am also now getting "Lambda can't find the file index.js. Make sure that your handler upholds the format: file-name.method."